# interface adat from a yamaha ls9

Tags: adat

I have the LS9 and the MY16-AT. I also have the Focusrite safire pro40 and the behringer fca610. has anyone hooked up ADAT to this setup? yamaha manuals are lacking for adat, even lack routing information to get out the adat 16 channels?

Answer (score 0):

MY16-AT is a slot option card. Slot Option cards are detailed in the LS9 manual. For example page 95-6 outlines how to configure output patching with reference to internally hosted ports and slot option ports. You will find what you need in the LS9 Owners manual.